# Undefined reference error when trying to include header from same project

Tags: c++11

I have a method I've defined like this:

```
int generate(const char* infile, std::vector<uint8_t> &detection, int another_flag);
```

I wanted `detection` to be a reference to the vector passed into it (hence the &), so that changes in this method happens to the original and hang around when the method exits.

I've built that method into a shared library. In the same project I've written a test program that imports the header:

```
#import <extract.hpp>
```

In the test program I'm calling the method like this:

```
    const char* infile = argv[1];
    std::vector<uint8_t> detection;
    int ret;
    ret = generate(infile, detection, 0);
```

It compiles, but it won't link, complaining:

```
undefined reference to `generate(char const*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, int)'
```

I'm attempting to build the project using cmake.
The entry for the test file is as follows:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) <-- the location of extract.hpp
add_executable(harness harness.cpp)
target_include_directories(harness PRIVATE include) <-- desperate attempt
target_link_libraries(harness ${CV_LIBS})
```

This file is referenced from another CMakeLists file using an `add_subdirectory(test)` command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you changed the declaration of the method, but not the definition (i.e. body).

Comment: @JacobDlougach Can you please clarify? The method signature in the header file and the implementation are the same...

Comment: Does the declaration of `generate` appear before the method you're using it in?

Comment: @Victor nope - I've just updated the question, because I think it's about my cmake setup and linking now, rather than compiling.

Comment: Did you add the library to cmake? (add_library?)

Comment: @E.vanPutten I didn't - I needed to add it into the target_link_libraries call so it would be: `target_link_libraries(harness ${CV_LIBS} extract)`! Thanks for the heads up. If you add it as an answer I'll tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just found it wasn't linking the library. Apparently it needed to get added to the `target_link_libraries` call so it would be:

```
target_link_libraries(harness ${CV_LIBS} extract)
```